# Apply styles to parent document from child document

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, dom

I have a script of chat widget application and want to apply styles to parents documents body from child document(chat widget application).
So if you look in the image I want to apply styles to parents document body from app-chat-wdget.

What i have tried so far - I try to access using window object but it gives me child document.

[image]

frameElement is null
[image]

I tried to access through `window.parent` but it doesn't have parent document - 
[image: frameEl.document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(css);]

Even `window.top` doesn't have parent document
[image]

Comment: Note also that without jQuery you can use `window.top` or `window.parent` to access parent window object(s). N/A from a different domain or when sandboxed.

Comment: I tried both and attached screeshots but i am not able to access parent document. Would you please look at it. And if you think this question has not been answered please removed the duplicate. thanks

Comment: To help re-opening the question, please edit it to include the code that tries to find the parent or top window's document object and fails. Details of the error produced are important. Also, could you indicate (in the question) if all pages' html is being served from local host port 4201 - different ports on the same server are considered different domains. Thanks.

Comment: @traktor53 Yes both are running on different ports I think that’s why

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple: you **CANNOT**. But... you can use a script to do it. In the child page, you could have something like this:

```
var frameEl = window.parent;
if (frameEl) {
    var css = document.createElement('link');
    css.rel = 'stylesheet";
    css.type = '"text/css"';   
    css.href = "http://....";
    frameEl.document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(css);
}
```

Comment: window.frameElement is null

Comment: my bad! it should have been "window.parent"

Comment: window.parent doesn't have document. For that reason `frameEl.document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(css);` is giving me error.